# How to use useIntercom() from react-use-intercom in class component?

Tags: reactjs, intercom

I am using react-use-intercom.

Using following hook from the guide [react-use-intercom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-use-intercom?activeTab=explore) which suggests to use functional components everywhere.

```
const { boot, shutdown, hide, show, update } = useIntercom();
```

However I am using class components everywhere, is there any way that I can do use it in class component itself, because the official documentation has examples in functional component only.
I want to use this methods on click of a button, i.e on some events.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use hooks in class component, which is a rule from React. There is a way to get pass that. You can create a functional component with useIntercom, pass the state or function as props to your class component. For example:

```
function Intercom(){
  const intercom = useIntercom();
  return <YourComponent {...intercom} />
}
```

For example, you now can use the boot function in your component like
`this.props.boot()`